# Returning a array from a void * argument in a function

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, pass-by-value

I have a variadic function that takes at least 3 arguments, and is of the form

```
foo(void* ret_val, int mode, int num_params, ...)
```

The general use of the variadic function `foo()` can involve returning different data types as well as an arbitrary number of input arguments that can have various data types, but I am unable to find a way of returning an array.

How can I return an array?

The function definition is that the first argument returns an arbitrary type depending on the function invoked by `foo()`, `mode` is the mode of operation, and `num_params` is the number of additional input parameters, which can be zero. There is a `switch` statement inside `foo()` which depending on `mode`, can invoke one or more functions, and can return a value of an arbitrary type.

As a simplified example, suppose I have the following 3 functions that are invoked by `foo()`:

```
void bar1(int i, int, j) {
// Do some calculations but return nothing.
}

int bar2() {
// Do some calculations and return a value.
}

int* bar(3) {
// Do some calculations with an array and return it.
}
```

Then in `foo()` I can have the following code:

```
foo(void* ret_val, int mode, int num_params, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, num_params);
  switch (mode) {
  case 1: {
          int a = va_arg(args, int);
          int b = va_arg(args, int);
          bar1(a, b);
          }
          break;
  case 2: {
          int val = bar1();
          *(int*)ret_val = val;
          }
          break;
  case 3: {
          int* p = new int[10];
          p = bar3();
          // Add a loop to test out that the array has been read from bar3(), which works.
          *(int*)ret_val = *p; // <== This is where the problem is.
          }
          break;
      }
      va_end(args);
}
```

Then in the main program I can invoke `foo()` in the following way:

```
int x;
foo(&x, 1, 2, 10, 20); // Call bar1()

foo(&x, 2, 0);         // Call bar2()
printf("%d\n", x);

int xd[10];            // Declare and initialize xd.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    xd[i] = 0;
}
foo(xd, 3, 0)          // Call bar3()
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d %d\n", i, xd[i]);
}
```

I put in the calls for `bar1()` and `bar2()` for context, and they work. For `bar1()` two ints are provided, but nothing is returned, and a dummy output argument has to be provided. For `bar2()` no input values are given, but an output int is returned, which is cast to star(int star) which works and is returned correctly.

However, for `bar3()` internally I generate a 10 element array as a test, which is correctly returned inside `foo()` from the print statement, but I am unable to return the array to `main()`. I have fiddled around with various statements involving pointers, but either a list of zeros is returned if the array is initialized, or garbage if it is not.

How can I return an array correctly?

Comment: This is not C; C does not have a `new` operator as in `new int[10];`. Are you writing in C or C++?

Comment: Change `int xd[10];` to `int *xd;` and call to be `foo(&xd, 3, 0)`. Also need `*(int*)ret_val = *p;` to be `*(int**)ret_val = p;` (assuming `bar3` returns an `int *`.

Comment: In `foo(xd, 3, 0)`, do you want `foo` to fill in an array that is passed to it by way of the first argument or do you want it to return a pointer to an array it has allocated by putting a pointer to the first element of that array in `xd`?

Comment: How is this function supposed to be invoked exactly? What is `ret_val` supposed to point to?

Comment: @kaylum: That is insufficient. Then they are passing an `int **` as a `void *` but accessing it in `foo` as an `int *`.

Comment: `int* p = new int[10]; p = bar3();` That doesn't make sense. The second statement throws away the memory allocated by the first. Did you mean to either pass `p` into `bar3` or have `bar3` return a newly allocated array?

Comment: Honestly and don't get me wrong, but it seems you've made a hash/hack trying things out in C++.  I know what your proposed "solution" is, but what was the original problem, where you had to resort to writing code this way?  Just having a glance at what you're trying to accomplish, C++ function objects and/or templates would have been the method I would have initially chosen to use.

Comment: I changed from C to C++. I don't know of any other language that would handle this code.

Comment: Even [this quick and dirty implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eba288c485ad84f2) is not the best, but at the very least, it works, the interface for the client is simple (no need to specify the number of arguments, just the mode), and there is no need for varargs.  I am going by the use-case you posted.

Answer (score 0):

In this call

```
foo(xd, 3, 0)
```

the array designator `xd` is converted to pointer to its first element and the function deals with a copy of this value.

Within the function this statement

```
*(int*)ret_val = *p;
```

just changes the first element of the array `xd` with the value of the first element of the array pointed to by the pointer `p`.

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. You can not assign one array to another as for example

```
int a[10] = { /*...*/ };
int b[10] = { /*...*/ };

a = b;
```

So this code snippet

```
      int* p = new int[10];
      p = bar3();
      // Add a loop to test out that the array has been read from bar3(), which works.
      *(int*)ret_val = *p;
```

does not make a sense. Moreover it seems there is a memory leak because at first the pointer `p` was assigned with the address of the allocated memory

```
  int* p = new int[10];
```

and then reassigned with the value returned by the function `bar3`.

```
  p = bar3();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `foo` as shown below (in C, as this question was originally tagged). Comments show how to think about `ret_val`. Note that the interface for `bar3` has been changed.

```
/*  ret_val is a pointer to some type T, a "T *", that has been converted to
    "void *".  To use it, we convert it back to its original type "T *".
*/
foo(void *ret_val, int mode, int num_params, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num_params);

    switch (mode)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            //  T is void.  Nothing is returned via ret_val.
            int a = va_arg(args, int);
            int b = va_arg(args, int);
            bar1(a, b);
        }
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            /*  We will return an int, so T is an int, and we convert ret_val
                back to "int *".
            */
            int val = bar1();

            //  Return val.
            * (int *) ret_val = val;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            /*  We will return a pointer to an int, so T is an "int *", and
                we convert ret_val back to "int **".
            int *p = malloc(10 * sizeof p);
            if (!p)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error, memory allocation failed.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            bar3(p);

            //  Return p.
            * (int **) ret_val = p;
        }
        break;
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

Then, for case 3, you can call `foo` with:

```
int *xd;
foo(&xd, 3, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry for messing about with the language tags. OP originally tagged it with both C and C++ and it's not C. Multilanguage tagging... :-/